# Tailwind css is not working in angular components

Tags: angular, sass, tailwind-css

I have implemented tailwind css inside my angular project.
Tailwind css is working at root level in project, but it is not working in the scss placed inside any components.
Do I have to build every scss file inside the components? or is there any permanent solution for that?

Comment: How do you import tailwind only in your `app.component.scss` or also in  `styles.scss`? I think could be something wrong in the way package has been imported! Check this guide if you haven't yet:
https://dev.to/seankerwin/angular-8-tailwind-css-guide-3m45

Comment: I go through the above link and it is working till root level only.
To build style css I have created output.css and build it to style css. Now tailwind is working for style css because build code is written for it. I have no idea about how to build css inside any components.

Comment: @HardiShah can you maby provide us with a more clearer explanantion? I'm facing the same issue. Where code in my components is not getting any styling. While I move the div out of a component (Google Chrome) I see the html styled and all.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Finally in Angular CLI [v11.2](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8427) now supports tailwind out of the box

```
# install tailwind
npm install --save tailwindcss
# create `tailwind.config.js`
npx tailwindcss init

Then disable view encapsulation of the component
```